# Get all the belongsTo relations plus some HABTM at CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to get only one `HABTM` relationship when using `paginate` using CakePHP 2.3.

Right now I'm getting this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Ticket] => Array ( .....)
            [User] => Array ( .....)
            [Priority] => Array ( .....)
            [Status] => Array(....)
            [Attachment] => Array(....)
            ....
        )
    [1] => ....
    [2] => ....

)
```

By using:

```
    $this->Ticket->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 20
    );
```

I am using `$this->Ticket->recursive = 0;` because I'm only interested in the `belongsTo` relationships with other tables, but at the same time, I would like to get only one of the `HABTM` relationships.

I know I could achieve it adding each of the single relationships in the `contain` array, like so:

```
    $this->Ticket->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 20,
            'contain' => array(
                    'Ticket`, `User`, `Priority`, `Status`, `Attachment`, `Tags`...
            )
    );
```

But I have plenty of tables and I was wondering if there's any way to do it without having to name every single table in the `contain` array.

I've also tried to use the [`recursive` array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options) inside the `contains` one like so:

```
    //getting the filtered tickets
    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 20,
            'contain' => array(
                    'Ticket' => array('recursive' => 1),
                    'Tag' //this is the hasMany relationship 
            )
    );
```

But it didn't work. Is there any way to achieve this without having to name all the tables to make it more simple to maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as it seems there's no solution for it, I managed to do it by getting the associated models of the type `belongsTo` and then adding the model name of the HABTM relationship:

```
$associations = $this->Ticket->getAssociated('belongsTo');
$associations[] = 'Tag';

//getting the filtered tickets
$this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 20,
        'contain' => $associations
);
```